# Linux - Shell Script and Colorized Text

Tags: linux, shell

From my most recent post: [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046851/linux-colorizing-text-in-files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046851/linux-colorizing-text-in-files)
I can now colorize text, in my terminal window. (using `echo`)

Now I'm to the point that I'd like to run a Shell Script that will over-write my `/etc/issue` whenever I decide to execute my shell script.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# re-write /etc/issue
echo "Welcome Back!........whatever message I will put later on" > /etc/issue
```

So now I'm looking to colorize the text "Welcome Back!"

According to [This Site](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/issue01to08/lg_issue7.html#color_issue), I need to Escape my color codes by using Ctrl+V+ESC
But how does one do that inside a shell script, with the goal to re-write the `/etc/issue`?

I did copy and paste the author's example (rc.issue) that he gives.  Indeed, the `/etc/issue` file gets re-written upon boot, but no color. Just plain text shows.

Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Comment: Here's your answer. http://webhome.csc.uvic.ca/~sae/seng265/fall04/tips/s265s047-tips/bash-using-colors.html

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054973/how-to-show-text-color-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, which will work in most shells (not just `bash`) is to make sure the escape appears in the text of the shell script.

If you use `vim`, then you will still need to type <kbd>Control-V</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd> to enter the escape because otherwise escape changes from insert mode back to command mode.

Other editors may or may not have quirks to make this easier — or harder.

If you're using `bash` and don't care about portability, then there are other options available, using the `\e` notation for the escape (see the `bash` manual on [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)).  For example:

```
escape=$'\e'
```

This won't work with all other shells, though.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I do need to use the same escape method, within `vim`.